# insert multiple records one by one using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to copy `ProductStatisticsTemp` table data to `ProductStatistics` table,

```
var str = from a in db.ProductStatisticsTemp select a;

ProductStatistics ls = new ProductStatistics();

foreach (var val in str.ToList())
{                     
     ls.Product_ID = val.Product_ID;
     ls.ProductNameEn = val.ProductNameEn;
     ls.ProductNameAr = val.ProductNameAr;

     db.ProductStatistics.Add(ls);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

first record can insert but once its try to insert 2nd one getting following error

> The property 'Product_ID' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified.

Comment: You need to move `ProductStatistics ls = new ProductStatistics();` to inside the loop (and you can move `db.SaveChanges();` to after the loop).

Comment: If you want to use the same object then its all properties must be reset,

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have one instance of an object and try to add already added object twice.

You need to create new object of `ProductStatistics` in the loop.

Also you can save changes just once after the loop to improve performance by trigger DB communication just once:

```
var str = from a in db.ProductStatisticsTemp select a;

foreach (var val in str.ToList())
{                     
     ProductStatistics ls = new ProductStatistics
     {
         Product_ID = val.Product_ID,
         ProductNameEn = val.ProductNameEn,
         ProductNameAr = val.ProductNameAr
     };

     db.ProductStatistics.Add(ls);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: but how to save data to table row by row, not at once ?

Comment: @kez the main question is: What is the reason? You can call SaveChanges inside the loop but the result will be the same and you will have extra loading to the communication channel.

Comment: once I insert `SaveChanges` inside loop I'm getting error `An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.`

Comment: Well the best way is to see the inner exception for details. There is no problems which can cause this error and we need to have more info to answer your question.
Also I'm steel can't understand why do you need to save each row separately.

Comment: I want to save validated results only , dont want to insert invalid other results

Comment: Then you can prepare data first with validation or validate inside the loop and add only validated items and finally save it by calling `SaveChanges` once.

Comment: can I have an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106905/discussion-between-vadim-martynov-and-kez).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different method.

```
var products = db.ProductStatisticsTemp.Select(t => new ProductStatistics
                             {
                                 Product_ID = t.Product_ID,
                                 ProductNameEn = t.ProductNameEn,
                                 ProductNameAr = t.ProductNameAr
                             }).ToList()

db.ProductStatistics.AddRange(products);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Inspired from @Vadim Martynov

> If the **`Product_ID`** is your primary key, and your set to increment
>   the key from database . Do not do this `Product_ID = val.Product_ID`.
>   The key should be generated from the database. You will get the id
>   after save changes is invoked.

```
 try
 {
   var str = from a in db.ProductStatisticsTemp select a;

   //This will improve some performance
   db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

   foreach (var val in str.ToList())
   {                     
      ProductStatistics ls = new ProductStatistics
      {

         Product_ID = val.Product_ID,
         ProductNameEn = val.ProductNameEn,
         ProductNameAr = val.ProductNameAr
     };

     //use AddRange or Add based on your EF Version.
     db.ProductStatistics.Add(ls);
   }

  db.SaveChanges();
 }
 finally
 {
      db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
 }
```

> If you are using `AddRange` you could omit `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`

For more info about `DetectChanges` available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.DetectChanges)

> AddRange() method only support from EF6 see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
db.ProductStatistics.AddRange(products);
```

> What AddRange will do for you is

if `AutoDetectChangesEnabled is set to true` (which is the default), then DetectChanges will be called once before adding any entities and will not be called again.

> This means that in some situations AddRange may perform significantly
>   better than calling Add multiple times would do.

Note that entities that are already in the context in some other state will have their state set to Added. AddRange is a no-op for entities that are already in the context in the Added state.